# Finder/Quick Look Malfunction after 10.8 OS upgrade

Tags: finder, osx-mountain-lion, quicklook, .ds-store

I upgraded to 10.8 and cannot shake this issue at all.

I process image files daily as part of my work.  For some reason only since my upgrade to 10.8, at some point Finder cannot preview any image nor can Quick Look.  In order to get it back, I need to delete the DS-store file in that particular folder and relaunch Finder.  This works, but eventually it will malfunction again.

I can't figure out a pattern of when it malfunctions - it happens regardless if it is new files in a few folder, old files in an old folder that was working, new files in an old files, etc.

I've had a mac for 10 years and never once had this issue, so it's a bit maddening. Has anyone else experienced this or have suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Have you tried `qlmanage -r` or removing `/private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache/`?

Comment: **qlmanage -r cache** may also resolve the issue for a time, and **qlmanage -p document.pdf** with varying levels of debug might provide some clues to get you on the right path.

Comment: Are these files stored locally or are they being accessed from an AFP, CIFS/SMB, or NFS file share over the network?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using old Finder plugins on OSX 10.7 (Lion), such as TotalFinder, Fuse, you will need to upgrade it to the latest version to work with OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion).